# SQL convert table with Char(1) column to a single row

Tags: t-sql

Input table: Col Char(1)

```
Col  Seq
 A    1
 B    2 
 C    3 
 D    4
 etc
 Z   26
 A    1
 B    2
etc  
 Z    26
```

Want a result table:  Row char(26)

```
Row
ABCD...Z
ABCD...Z
 etc
```

Comment: share more details... do you want to insert into an existing table or or just want to do a `select`

Comment: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example.
Note i am not sure what your plan is with seq? or if you need the items in order? or if you need a distinct list? so check my comments.

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (Col CHAR(1),Seq INT)
INSERT INTO @Data
VALUES
    ('a',1),
    ('b',2),
    ('c',3),
    ('d',4)


SELECT
    STUFF(
   (
        SELECT  '' + Col
        FROM    @Data
        GROUP BY Col         --Remove duplicates
        ORDER BY Col         --Put it in order
      FOR XML PATH('')
   ),1,0,'')
```